# Available rooms in a hotel

Tags: mysql

I have tables:

```
hotel(id,name,description,suburb,date_from,date_to)
room_type(id,name,description,number_rooms,hotel_id,date_from,date_to)
booking(id,room_type,check_in,check_out,customer_id)
```

and `customer` table

I have made a query that looks like:

```
SELECT room_type.*, (room_type.number_rooms - count(booking.room_type_id)) as available_rooms 
FROM room_type,booking,hotel 
WHERE room_type.id = booking.room_type_id AND hotel.id = room_type.hotel_id
AND NOT ((check_out >= '2015-08-16' AND check_in >= '2015-08-25') 
OR (check_out <= '2015-08-16' AND check_out <= '2015-08-25'))
group by room_type.id;
```

This query only returns results if at least one booking has been made.
Rooms without bookings are not returned.

Help with an appropriate query that returns available rooms would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question with (1) an explanation of what you are trying to do; (2) sample data; (3) desired results.  A non-working query doesn't really convey very much information.

Comment: ...although it shows us that you have at least tried, which is nice.

Comment: Did you make an error in your query? `check_out <= '2015-08-16' AND check_out <= '2015-08-25'` doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @ESG I suspect that there's lots and lots wrong here. It's not a case of a simple typographical fix.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, some silly mistakes, but I eventually got it right.